# What will be the advantage of storing information provided by claims from OIDC token in a database

Tags: java, spring-security, jwt, openid-connect

I'm using a OIDC token in my Spring Java application that contains all the claims that I need in order to identify the user and the roles for the application.

I will store later all this data in the format required by the UserDetails class used by Spring Security context. What will be the advantage of persisting the data in a user table and a roles tables in order to be retrieved latter? Could I relay only on the claims from the token?

Answer (score 1):

I can not see any advantage in saving claims in a DB:

- saving claims in DB is costly. Retrieving it from the DB is costly too (less, but still) when the claims should be present in the JWT (or retrieved when introspection an opaque token) attached to each and every request.
- access-token has a (short) expiry time. Do you intend to implement something to delete the claims from DB at expiration?

You **should** rely on the data in the token (or attached to it in case of introspection). This data is emitted, signed and controlled by the authorization-server which should be the only reference for identities.

Comment: I  don't intend to delete the claims from db on token expiration, just update them (ex roles) and last login time next time when we will have the token from the user.

Comment: can you please heck my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74942522/validate-jwt-token-with-com-nimbusds-jose-and-a-public-certificate-url-from-azur . I saw you have a lot of experience with Spring security. thank you :-)