# Validate JWT token with com.nimbusds.jose and a public certificate url from Azure AD

Tags: spring-security, azure-active-directory, bearer-token, nimbus-jose-jwt

I'm using a com.nimbusds.jose implementation in order to validate a token by retrieving the public key which was used to sign the JWT from Microsoft authorization server configuration (property jwks_uri). When I'm trying to validate the token by using the code written below, I'm getting:

> com.nimbusds.jose.RemoteKeySourceException: Couldn't retrieve remote JWK set: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target.
>
> Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Code:

```
 try {
        ConfigurableJWTProcessor jwtProcessor = new DefaultJWTProcessor();
        JWKSource keySource = null;
        try {
          ResourceRetriever jwkRetriever = new DefaultResourceRetriever(100000, 100000);
          JWKSetCache jwkSetCache = new DefaultJWKSetCache(1440,
              1430, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
          keySource = new RemoteJWKSet(new URL(
              "https://login.windows.net/36799f34-92fd-4612-8473-80173f2406e8/discovery/v2.0/keys"),jwkRetriever,jwkSetCache);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
        JWSAlgorithm expectedJWSAlg = JWSAlgorithm.RS256;
        JWSKeySelector keySelector = new JWSVerificationKeySelector(expectedJWSAlg,keySource);
        jwtProcessor.setJWSKeySelector(keySelector);

        JWTClaimsSet claimsSet = null;
        SecurityContext ctx = null; // optional context parameter, not required here
        try {
          claimsSet = jwtProcessor.process(token, ctx);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (BadJOSEException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JOSEException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I've added the certificates in the truststore. See below the configuration from Spring application.properties file:

```
    trust.store=myapp_dev.p12
trust.store.password=changeit
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is the root authority of your certificate known by the `cacerts` file of the JRE the app throwing this exception is running into?

Comment: Yes, I've imported the pem file into my Mac Java cacerts location. Same java version used by my application.